# Mirror Equation for convex mirror

Tags: optics, reflection

**Question:**
I have a convex lens with focal length $\mathrm{70mm}$ and it's forming a *real image*. We have a *virtual object* at $\mathrm{90mm}$ to the right of the mirror. Using the mirror equation gives the wrong solution.

**Image for clarification**:[image]

**My attempt:**

1. $v$ (object distance)=$\mathrm{+90mm}$
2. $u$ (image distance)= unknown
3. $f$ (focal length)=$\mathrm{+70mm}$

Using mirror formula, $\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}$
I get $v$=$\mathrm{+135mm}$

**Problem:**
I was expecting $v$ to come with a negative sign since image formed on left side of mirror.

**PS:**

1. I am using Cartesian convention (direction of incident light taken
   as positive and other as negative).
2. The question is about why using the virtual object messes up
   answer from mirror equation.
3. I am aware that other convention also exists (in which $f$ for convex
   lens is negative, however this convention is the one i need to know
   where it goes wrong).
4. [Edit After @Infinite suggested that the diagram May be wrong] The
   diagram actually comes from the secondary mirror in a cassegrain
   telescope (like [here](http://slittlefair.staff.shef.ac.uk/teaching/phy241/lectures/L03/files/small_2436.gif)).Though I think that if both the ray diagram and
   the calculation is correct and my use of mirror equation is correct then the
   only thing left is the data itself (70mm,etc),which is incorrect.
   **But to conclude that I need to know that I correctly used the mirror equation here.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is correct. We have to judge the diagram by obtaining the results from the formula but not just simply imagining a diagram. The results suggest that your diagram was wrong and the correct diagram could be the below one:

[image]

---

Extending the comments:
 To get a real image the virtual object should lie in between pole and the focus. We can prove this result from mirror formula. From the sign conventions, we have $f>0$ ,$u>0$ and $v$ should be less than zero (for forming real image).
So from mirror formula, $ \frac{1}{v}=\frac{1}{f}-\frac{1}{u} <0$ $\implies u<f$

Comment: 1)Thanks for the attempt.  2)I probably should have mentioned that the question above is a part of a bigger question involving cassegrain telescope (like in this image: http://slittlefair.staff.shef.ac.uk/teaching/phy241/lectures/L03/files/small_2436.gif). So, the diagram in the original post is like the secondary mirror of a cassegrain telescope.   3)But i think if my calculation is correct and the dig. is correct then the data itself might be wrong...?

Comment: Yes, there could be some mistake in the data.

Comment: @JustCurious: Your calculation is correct as per data. The diagram provided by infinite is also correct. To obtain the kind of image you have in link, ensure that your virtual object lies between focus and pole.

Comment: @Sabat Anwar So only if the virtual object is between pole and focus will i achieve a real image? Can you direct me to some proof of the said statement. (I accepted the answer btw).

Comment: @JustCurious I will include it in my answer.

Comment: @Infinite Thanks a lot..!!